# Error "list index out of range" Python

Tags: python, lista

estoy teniendo un problema que no tiene mucho sentido, estoy realizando una comunicación serie entre Arduino y Python, Arduino está mandando dos valores y para intentar leerlos, realizo lo que se ve en el código, el problema es que no me deja acceder al segundo elemento de la lista, es decir, a values[1].

```
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem141101', 57600, timeout=1)
arduino.flushInput()

while 1:
    rawString = arduino.readline()
    values=rawString.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r\n').split('|')
    print(values)
    print(values[0])
    #print(values[1])
```

Al ejecutar ese código, me da la siguiente salida:

['1', '-4']

1

Pero al intentar imprimir solo values[1], me sale **IndexError: list index out of range**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿has verificado que la indentación es la misma? Es decir, en el código que ahora te funciona, cambias [0] por [1], ¿te sigue apareciendo el error?

Comment: No entiendo lo de la indentación, pero si, cuando accedo al elemento [0], no tengo problemas, cuando accedo a los dos juntos imprimiendo values, tampoco, pero cuando intento imprimir solo values[1], si me da error

Comment: Hola Adrián, podrías quitar todos los prints y agregar  justo debajo de la línea `values=rawString....` y a su mismo nivel de identación lo siguiente: `print("ERROR: ",repr(values),"solo tiene",len(values),"items") if len(values) != 2 else print("V0:", values[0], "V1:", values[1])`, tal como está en una sola línea. Si te imprime algún `ERROR...` muestra lo que te imprime literalmente, copiando y pegando la salida en la pregunta . Lo que comentas es muy raro, algo se nos escapa...